# How to use log4j2 to log log4j logs

Tags: java, logging, log4j2

I got log4j2 configure within my application but some of my third party dependencies use log4j (1.2). Is there is a way to use log4j2.xml to log, logs that coming from log4j?

or do I have to maintain two configuration files, one for log4j2 and one for log4j.

This is the log4j2 config which I use;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration>
  <Properties>
    <Property name="logFiles">./logs</Property>
  </Properties>
  <Appenders>
    <Console name="sysOut" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
      <PatternLayout pattern="%d %-5p [%t] %C{2} (%F:%L) - %m%n"/>
    </Console>
   <Loggers>
        <logger name="org.sample.core" level="debug">
            <AppenderRef ref="sysOut"/>
        </logger>       

        <Logger name="org.apache.log4j.xml" level="debug">      
            <AppenderRef ref="sysOut"/>
        </Logger>
        <Root level="warn">
            <AppenderRef ref="sysOut"/>
        </Root>
  </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way is to use the log4j-1.2 bridge jar that is included in log4j2.
See the [Log4j 1.2 Migration Guide](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/migration.html). (Make sure to remove the legacy log4j-1.2.x.jar from your classpath!)

You will only need the Log4j 2 configuration.

Answer (score 0):

First excludes every log4j12 dependency in other third party dependencies:

```
<exclusions>
  <exclusion>
    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
  </exclusion>
  <exclusion>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
  </exclusion>
</exclusions>
```

then add log4j-over-slf4j dependency, anything that normally requires log4j which is excluded above will use log4j-over-slf4j instead.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-over-slf4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.13</version>
</dependency>
```